# Webpack config file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am new in using React and trying to configure webpack.config.js file as below:

```
import path from 'path'

    module.exports = {
        entry : './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
            filename : 'bundle.js',
        },
        module:{
            rules:[
                {
                    test:/\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader:'babel-loader',
                },
            ],
        },
    };
```

but when I try to run the webpack command to generate the bundle file I got the below error:

Must use import to load ES Module:  \webpack.config.js
I haven't used 'require' in this file and can't find the error reason.
below is my some part of my package.jason:

```
{
  "name": "fulljs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "Full JS Project",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --ignore public/",
    "dev": "webpack -wd "
  },
```

and also I am using as:
npm 6.14.4
webpack 4.43.0

Comment: try `const path = require('path')`

Comment: The same error if I use const path = require('path')

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
const path = require('path');
```

Instead of :

```
import path from 'path'
```

Comment: The same error if i use: const path = require('path')